# Join multiple tables, select counts from different tables and group by one column in one query

Tags: sql

I need to join multiple tables, select counts from different tables and group by one column in one query.  This is how I would do this separately:

```
select      c.CommunityName, SUM(case when m.ListKey = c.ListKey then 1 else 0 end) as Posts
from        Community c with(NOLOCK)
join        messages_ m with(NOLOCK)
on          c.ListKey = m.ListKey
group by    c.CommunityName

select      c.CommunityName, SUM(case when b.CommunityKey = c.CommunityKey then 1 else 0 end) as Blogs
from        Community c with(NOLOCK)
join        Blog b with(NOLOCK)
on          c.CommunityKey = b.CommunityKey
group by    c.CommunityName

select      c.CommunityName, SUM(case when ce.CommunityKey = c.CommunityKey then 1 else 0 end) as Events
from        Community c with(NOLOCK)
join        CalendarEvent ce with(NOLOCK)
on          c.CommunityKey = ce.CommunityKey
where       ce.StartDateTime >= GETDATE()
group by    c.CommunityName
```

or simply

```
select      c.CommunityName, COUNT(*)
from        Community c with(NOLOCK)
join        messages_ m with(NOLOCK)
on          c.ListKey = m.ListKey
group by    c.CommunityName

select      c.CommunityName, COUNT(*)
from        Community c with(NOLOCK)
join        Blog b with(NOLOCK)
on          c.CommunityKey = b.CommunityKey
group by    c.CommunityName

select      c.CommunityName, COUNT(*)
from        Community c with(NOLOCK)
join        CalendarEvent ce with(NOLOCK)
on          c.CommunityKey = ce.CommunityKey
where       ce.StartDateTime >= GETDATE()
group by    c.CommunityName
```

There are more tables, some that require additional joins...  Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you not UNION them all together, adding a static text field to distinguish each group?

Comment: I'm still a baby SQL wizard ;) I'll check out UNION. Thanks!

Comment: What should your result be? sum of all the counts from different queries?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for community name along with the counts such as posts, blogs, event etc..

As your queries count individually, add dummy columns in the `SELECT` for the other counts and then in the end `UNION` them and get the `SUM`.

```
SELECT CommunityName , SUM(MessageCount), SUM(BlogCount), SUM(EventCount)
FROM (
    SELECT      c.CommunityName CommunityName , COUNT(*) MessageCount, 0 BlogCount, 0 EventCount
    FROM        Community c with(NOLOCK)
    JOIN        messages_ m with(NOLOCK)
    ON          c.ListKey = m.ListKey
    GROUP BY    c.CommunityName

    UNION

    SELECT      c.CommunityName, 0, COUNT(*), 0
    FROM        Community c with(NOLOCK)
    JOIN        Blog b with(NOLOCK)
    ON          c.CommunityKey = b.CommunityKey
    GROUP BY    c.CommunityName

    UNION

    SELECT      c.CommunityName, 0, 0, COUNT(*)
    FROM        Community c with(NOLOCK)
    JOIN        CalendarEvent ce with(NOLOCK)
    ON          c.CommunityKey = ce.CommunityKey
    WHERE       ce.StartDateTime >= GETDATE()
    GROUP BY    c.CommunityName
  ) CountsTable
GROUP BY CountsTable.CommunityName
```

`CountsTable` will look like

```
| COMMUNITYNAME | MESSAGECOUNT | BLOGCOUNT | EVENTCOUNT |
|---------------|--------------|-----------|------------|
|          Name |           10 |         0 |          0 |
|          Name |            0 |        20 |          0 |
|          Name |            0 |         0 |         30 |
```

So, you can `GROUP BY` name and sum up the counts to get your result

```
| COMMUNITYNAME | MESSAGECOUNT | BLOGCOUNT | EVENTCOUNT |
|---------------|--------------|-----------|------------|
|          Name |           10 |        20 |         30 |
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I ended up asking one of our SQL geniuses on staff for help - but obviously wanted to try to find the answer myself. This is exactly what he suggested! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck trying different techniques for 3 hours until I tried this!

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using `LEFT JOIN` to connect your tables? Then you can check for NULLs and sum up the non-NULL values.

```
SELECT
    c.CommunityName,
    SUM(case when m.ListKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as Posts,
    SUM(case when b.CommunityKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as Blogs,
    SUM(case when ce.CommunityKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as Events
FROM
    Community c WITH(NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN
    messages_ m WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON c.ListKey = m.ListKey
        LEFT JOIN
    Blog b WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON c.CommunityKey = b.CommunityKey
        LEFT JOIN
    CalendarEvent ce WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON c.CommunityKey = ce.CommunityKey
WHERE
    ce.StartDateTime >= GETDATE()
GROUP BY
    c.CommunityName
```